# Xrandr won't correct screen orientation

Tags: xrandr, display-rotation

I changed from Debian 9 to Ubuntu 17.10 today. I was on facebook when suddenly my screen turned upside down. That has already happened sometimes when I used Debian, so I just tried the usual command

> xrandr -o normal

However, it didn't work. I started looking at the internet and tried other solutions, such as

> xrandr --output  --rotate normal

It also didn't work. I can't rotate left, right or upside down either. My computer is an HP Elitebook 8440p and I am using only the notebook screen, no other monitors connected. When I logged off from my user, the screen was in the correct orientation, but logging in back turned it upside down again. How can I solve it?

Obs.: Restarting the machine worked, but do I need to do it everytime?

Comment: xrandr does not work with Wayland

Comment: And screens do not turn upside down out of the blue. Something is making it behave that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My computer is also a hp, in my case the orientation sensor is under the keyboard rather than the screen so UBUNTU and GNOME make things difficult.

To return the screen to normal incline the computer, pretend that the screen is the keyboard and the keyboard the screen; in that orientation the screen will return to normal. Now go to the top right menu and check for the 3 buttons in the bottom, the middle one is to lock the screen rotation, click it and the screen will no longer change orientation.

Comment: The OP has a HP Elitebook 8440p which have no such features.

Comment: Seems to have fixed it for me on a HP2540p Elitebook